# CopyPaste a web site

Tags: web-scraping, screen-scraping, imacros

I want to extract the HTML content of a web page as a text string then paste it into a form.

When I run my macro, I expect the form field to show the extracted HTML content. Instead it shows the literal string `"EXTRACT"` (which is what I thought the variable name was).

How do I get the actual extracted html content into the form? And specifically, what variable name to reference for the extracted content?

Specifically, the issue is at `CONTENT=EXTRACT`. What should `EXTRACT` actually be? Because as of now, it seems to be being translated as a literal string, not the variable reference I intended.

my-imacro.iim

```
VERSION BUILD=1234567 RECORDER=FX

'Extract data from target
TAB OPEN
TAB T=2
URL GOTO=http://www.example.com/my-products.php
TAG POS=1 TYPE=HTML ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT

'Submit data to form
TAB OPEN
TAB T=3
URL GOTO=https://docs.google.com/forms/d/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/viewform
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:mG61Hd ATTR=NAME:Extraction<SP>Results CONTENT=EXTRACT
TAG POS=2 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:quantumWizButtonPaperbuttonFocusOverlay&&TXT:
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Submit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the extract as a variable reference like this:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:mG61Hd ATTR=NAME:Extraction<SP>Results CONTENT={{!EXTRACT}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The section labeled ***Manipulate extraction*** [on this web page shows the following example](http://wiki.imacros.net/EVAL) of how to use `{{!EXTRACT}}`

Manipulate extraction

```
VERSION BUILD=7400919 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/preparing-for-handsets.html
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=P ATTR=TXT:Early<SP>this<SP>year,* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.toUpperCase()")
PROMPT {{!VAR1}}
```

[And here is a possibly even better example](http://wiki.imacros.net/Demo-ExtractAndFill).

http://wiki.imacros.net/Demo-ExtractAndFill

```
VERSION BUILD=10.4.28.1074
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
URL GOTO=http://demo.imacros.net/Automate/ExtractDemo

TAG POS=39 TYPE=TD ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}} 
SET !EXTRACT NULL

TAG POS=40 TYPE=TD ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR2 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL

TAG POS=41 TYPE=TD ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR3 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL

'Now fill them in a form. This is only one example. You could use it also as part of link  
URL GOTO=http://demo.imacros.net/Automate/TestForm1   
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:demo ATTR=NAME:name CONTENT=***Extract<SP>and<SP>Fill<SP>Demo*** 
'
'The variables are part of the CONTENT tag. You could use them as part of link
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:demo ATTR=NAME:Remarks CONTENT=Extraction<SP>results:<BR><BR>One<SP>dollar<SP>costs<SP>{{!VAR1}}<SP>EURO,<SP>{{!VAR2}}<SP>Pounds<SP>or<SP>{{!VAR3}}<SP>Yen.
```